# How do I make a command line argument an integer but if given a non-numeric value ask again?

Tags: powershell, error-handling, command-line-arguments

My script asks for a number of users `$numUsers` in the form of a command line argument. I then use that number to declare an array of size `$numUsers`.

It works fine when the user provides a number but when given a non-numeric character I need to ask for an it again.

Currently my code just fails and throws an ugly error message.

```
$numUsers = Read-Host -Prompt 'Specify how many users'
$userArray = New-Object string[] $numUsers
```

I have tried using a recursive function to convert the command line arg to an int and if that fails just ask for an arg again but it fails as well.

```
function makeInt {
    param([string]$numString)
    try { $newNum = [int]$numString }
    catch { makeInt (Read-Host -Prompt 'try again') }
    }

$numUsers = Read-Host -Prompt 'Specify how many users'
makeInt $numUsers
$userArray = New-Object string[] $numUsers
```

I tried several other ways as well but this is as close as I got in the last few days. Hopefully someone can help!

Answer (score 2):

If the only constraint you want to impose is that the user input be convertible to an `[int]`, you can use the [`[int]::TryParse()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse#System_Int32_TryParse_System_String_System_Int32__) in a loop:

```
[int] $number = -1
while (-not [int]::TryParse((Read-Host -Prompt 'Specify how many users'), [ref] $number)) {
    Write-Warning "Not a valid number, please try again."
}
# You only get here if the user (ultimately) provided valid input.
# $number then contains the user's input as an [int].
```

`[int]::TryParse()` *attempts* a conversion and if it succeeds, stores the `[int]` value in the variable passed *by reference* (`[ref]`) and returns `$True`;
if conversion isn't possible, `$False` is returned.

The `while` loop keeps prompting until valid input is provided, after which `$number` contains the `[int]` equivalent of the number string entered by the user.

Answer (score 0):

To validate if `$numUsers` is an `[int]` just put `[int]` in front of your `Read-Host` variable

```
 try{
     [int]$numUsers = Read-Host "Enter an number"
 }
catch
{
    Write-Host "Please enter a valid number"
}
```

However, if you want to continue to prompt the user until they enter a valid input, you would want to put it in a `do{}while()`

Ex. Solution:

```
function promptForUsers{
        [int](Read-Host 'Enter Number' )
    }

    do{

        try
        {
            $numUsers = promptForUsers; break
        }
        catch
        {
            Write-Warning "Not a number; please try again."
        }
    }while($true)
```